# How do I fix a "cannot bind parameter 'uri'. Cannot convert the...." when converting json in powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, api, weather-api

I am doing a `Get-Weather` project in powershell, where I pull data down from [weatherapi.com](https://www.weatherapi.com/) . I am able to successfully connect to the website using an API key but, when I try to convert it from json in the script it doesn't work. The error I get is:

> "Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert the..."
> I have tried so many different ways to write this:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method Get -ResponseHeadersVariable r -StatusCodeVariable s

$weatherobject = ConvertFrom-Json $url
```

The request for the website is:

```
$url = Invoke-WebRequest "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=$key&q=$location&days=$Days"
```

Any help would be very much apperciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input of the ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet is a JSON object. Look at the document below for more information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1#description

```
$url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=$key&q=$location&days=$Days"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method Get -ResponseHeadersVariable r -StatusCodeVariable s
$weatherobject = ConvertFrom-Json $response
```